# Blazemeter Script Runninf on Jmeter doesnt save data in DB

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am creating a script through Blazemeter (which storing some data in DB) and running through JMeter. Script is running fine but data is not stored in DB. What I am missing?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The chance of replaying recorded script is minimal as modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for [security reasons](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Token_Based_Mitigation) or [client-side state tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html#bnagr)

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of any dynamic parameters
3. With regards to "Script is running fine" - JMeter automatically treats responses with [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, so "green" result doesn't necessarily mean that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing. Try inspecting responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, most probably you're getting stuck at login page. Going forward you can consider adding [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in order to perform extra checks against the responses.

Comment: Thnks  Dmiriti for Answering my ans wer 1.i already added Cookie mangager.  2.i m reading my login parameter from csv file .3.i  m sure its not stuck on Login Page as DB Login Table updated

Comment: As i Just Found ,my application has url like 
***************/?uisessionid=150&event=loadapp&value=wotrack&_tt=vfciqpei0mh59n71sc5gbvu0u8 when it lends on a parituclar application Page 
and remain same as i click save button.
So Blazemeter records Same..
how to sort it out. i couldnt chagne post url in application as its IBM Tool